# Why shouldAutorotate() doesn't affect iPad while it works with iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am currently building an app that must not rotate at some point of time, I am therefore overriding the `shouldAutorotate()` method of my view controller, unfortunately, while I can prevent rotation on the iPhone, it doesn't affect iPad that still rotates !

Just for your information here is the code :

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}
```

Do you know what's wrong ? Does `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` interfere with `shouldAutorotate()`

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Check your `info.plist` and in it there should be`Supported interface orientations` and `Supported interface orientations (iPad)` check to make sure that the supported orientations on iPad are what you want them to be (same as iPhone I assume)

Comment: Oops, so sorry to never have answered you ! Well, from what I remember about the problem I had, the issue is that since the new versions of iOS, you can't do that as much easily as before ! (because resizing and rotation works different now, partly because of split view !)

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Did you solve the issue? If you did, you should add an answer for others who have this issue

Comment: That was for a game that used accelerometer, so if I am right, according to Apple UX guidelines, that's one of the rare cases where you can allow yourself to opt-out for split view, but I haven't had time to come back to that problem yet ! So I'll post it as soon as I'll solve it.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Ok. I can take my answer down if it doesn't help. I try not to keep answers up that don't help. That's why I came back to this

Comment: I think your answer might help eventually, maybe after disabling spit view, your answer will work, but since I didn't tested it correctly, I can't say it yet !

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise K. Good luck!